# display different results based on array value

Tags: php

I am trying to display a custom HTML page if the user that requests the page has the [is_vip] value equal to "5".

this is the line I'm trying to run:

```
 <?php if ($membership["is_vip"] == 5) { ?>
do stuff
    <?php } else { 
do other stuff
```

However it's not displaying the custom results properly, the contents of $membership look like this when printed.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => napify\Model\Membership Object
        (
            [is_vip] => 5
        )

)
```

This should be simple but i've been stuck in this for hours.

Comment: is it displaying the `else` section or ?

Comment: @smith no it's displaying none :(

Comment: then there are other issues at play, lets see the real code in context.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

That's an integer indexed array with one element containing an object.  Plus the code you posted won't parse and is a parse error.  Once you fix the syntax:

```
<?php if ($membership[0]->is_vip == 5) { ?>
 do stuff
<?php } else { ?>
 do other stuff
<?php } ?>
```

Make sure to use error reporting when developing:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: `do stuff` oh really thats real code?? @CharlesStover

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what someone would write who is testing if their `if` statement works as anticipated before they fill it in with their actual code. @smith

Comment: so not real then, glad we agree. @CharlesStover

Answer (score -1):

I believe AbraCadaver is correct with their post

```
<?php if ($membership[0]->is_vip == 5) { ?>
```

but there is also an issue with your closing tag.

```
<?php } else {
```

should be

```
<?php } else { ?>
```

and your else statement needs to be closed with a

```
<?php } ?>
```